# Mocking a GORM database with go-mocket doesn't work

Tags: go, mocking, go-gorm, mockups

I am trying to mock a gorm db by using go-mocket but it doesn't work as it should. I am not sending any mock-data to my ClusterExists function so that the unit test doesn't work as I expect.

In the documentation there're two ways of mocking "Simple chain usage" and "FakeResponse". I've tried with both ways and It doesn't work neither.

My function:

```
func ClusterExists(cluster *Cluster, db *gorm.DB) bool {
    c := Cluster{}
    exists := !db.Where("cluster_name = ? AND env_type = ?", cluster.ClusterName, cluster.EnvType).First(&c).RecordNotFound()

    return exists
}
```

My Tests functions:

```
func SetupTests() *gorm.DB { 
mocket.Catcher.Register() 
mocket.Catcher.Logging = true
db, err := gorm.Open(mocket.DriverName, "connection_string")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
db.LogMode(true)
//models.DB = db

return db
}
```

```
func TestShouldUpdateStats(t *testing.T){
    t.Run("SIMPLE test", func(t *testing.T){
        DB := SetupTests()
        commonReply := []map[string]interface{}{{"cluster_name":"testname", "env_type":"envtype"}}
        mocket.Catcher.NewMock().WithQuery("SELECT * FROM clusters WHERE").WithReply(commonReply)

        //var declaration
        var testCluster Cluster
        testCluster.ClusterName = "testname"
        testCluster.EnvType = "envtype"

        //assert
        if ClusterExists(&testCluster, DB) {
            t.Errorf("There is a record in the database which already exists:")
        }
    })
}
```

As my testCluster.ClusterName and  testCluster.EnvType are the same content as I have in my database, I should receive the error:

> t.Errorf("There is a record in the database which already exists:")

But I never receive a 'true' from the ClusterExists function so, I can't make to fail the test.

Do yo know what I am doing wrong with Go-Mocket? Is there something that I am missing?

Kind Regards!

Comment: For mocking SQL databases, [go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I have matched my query by using only 'WithArgs()' function and it works for me :)

mocket.Catcher.NewMock().WithArgs("testname","envtypes").WithReply(commonReply)